# Differentiate one element from array of nine having 8 elements with same value and 1 with different value?

Tags: java, c++

I have an array of 9 elements in which 8 elements have same value and one has different value. The problem is that you have only two if statements?

```
int main(){
int array[9];
for(int x=0;x<9;x++)
{
cin>>array[x];
}
if(){}
if(){}
cout<<"The number which is different is at ? position"
}
```

Comment: *"The problem is that you have only two if statements?"* Huh?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: yes i can only compare elements two time in my program

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Find the index of the "odd man out"?

Comment: I think you can have more that 2 if statements in your code, but only 2 if statements can be used to determine which ball is different. However, if you only know that one of nine balls is different it will take 3 if statements. If you know that the one of nine balls is heavier, it will take 2 if statements. If you know that the one of nine balls is lighter, it will take 2 if statements.

Comment: I think after the question is edited to also show the code, it is more clear and down votes might be removed. :)

Comment: I have an answer that works with one if-else statement and a for loop. Does this break the requirements of the problem? Unfortunately I cannot post the answer because this question has been put on hold. This looks like an artificial problem for a course or interview, rather than a real-world programming problem when you wouldn't restrict yourself to "two if statements"!

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] myArray = new int[]{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
Arrays.sort(myArray);
int indexOfdifferentValue = -1;
if(myArray[0] == myArray[1]){
indexOfdifferentValue = myArray.length - 1;
}else{
indexOfdifferentValue = 0;
}
int result = myArray[indexOfdifferentValue];
```

See if this works.

Ok here is a dirty solution perhaps. Its not a general solution, its only to address your situation. Check if this works for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int position = 0;

    int[] array = new int[]{1, 1, 1, 
                            1, 2, 1, 
                            1, 1, 1};

//      for(int x=0; x<9; x++){
//          cin>>array[x];
//      }

    if((array[position] == array[++position]) 
            && (array[++position] == array[++position])
            && (array[++position] == array[++position])
            && (array[++position] == array[++position])){

        position = position + 1;
    }


    if(position != (array.length - 1) && array[position] == array[position + 1]){
        position = position - 1;
    }

    System.out.println("The number which is different is at ? position: " + (position + 1) + ", index: " + position + ", value: " + array[position]);

}
```

Comment: I have edit my question. please check

Comment: This is a reasonable answer to a different question "What is the value of the different element". The (somewhat muddled) question asks for the index of the different value.

Comment: position variable at the end holds the index that is asked for.

Comment: Oops, you've edited your answer. My comment was based on the initial answer (before I refreshed). Your new answer is now wrong, returning 8 every time. Its' also not general. An answer that works for any size array would be preferable. I have an elegant answer, but cannot post...the idea is:
* set "numToDelete" as the first or last element (using one "if")
* set tmp = array[pos] - numToDelete; for each element (ie. all zero except different element)
* add tmp to one running total (total1)
* add (tmp*pos) to a 2nd running total (total2)
* posDifferent = (total2 / total1);

Comment: Pardon me but I am not here to argue with you. The question owner can tell if it worked for him or not. Yes I know it is not a general answer.

Secondly, I have run this code before posting. Its working quite fine.

Its java code just mentioning.

Comment: If you have an answer more elegant one i appreciate it. You can share with that solution via comments by pasting your link after putting that on https://ideone.com/

Comment: Also would like to see the correction to my code if you are feeling its wrong. I will be glad to learn about my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @muasif80: Apologies, not arguing. Just tried it in C++ in Visual Studio 2013. Tried different combinations of arrays and always got 8. I can see your idea, which is clever, but the logic is flawed. This might be related to the way java and C++ evaluate if statements ie. the value of "position" will be different on the two compilers. My comment prior to this will produce the right answer on all compilers and for any array size.

Comment: @muasif80: OK, done some more debugging in VS2013. The value of "position" after the first "if" statement is always 8, regardless of the position of the different element or DEBUG or RELEASE mode. Possibly a difference between the java and VC compilers.

Comment: Not agreed. It will work on C++ too. Anyways no more comments.